# AngularJS directive multiple views

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Lets say i have a customer model and i want to create different views of this model

e.g. one detail view:

- image
- first name
- last name
- email
- phone

and one showing only the picture and name:

- image
- first name, last name

Do i create multiple directives or do i create a view factory within a directive in this case?

The model i put in will always be a customer and the methods i call will also be the same.

Is there a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a "customer view" directive.

And controll its state by assigning different "showDetail" attribute. (I assume that your customer view only has two states)

This directive would being created like this

```
<customer-view customer-data="customer"></customer-view> <!-- Simple version -->
<customer-view customer-data="customer" show-detail="true"></customer-view> <!-- more detail -->
```

I wrote a simple example:

**Solution1 APP.js**

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("customerCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.customers = [{firstName:"Jimmy",lastName:"James",email:"jimmyj@gmail.com",phone:"000-00000-00"}];
})
.directive("customerView",function(){
  return {
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{
        showDetail:"@",
        customerData:"="
    },
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){

    },
    template: '<div><img src=""/><div><span>{{customerData.firstName}} {{customerData.lastName}}</span><div ng-show="showDetail"><span>Tel:{{customerData.phone}}</span></div><div ng-show="showDetail"><span>mail:{{customerData.email}}</span></div>'
  };
});
```

EDIT: If you don't want to use ng-show, you could try to identify the value of 'showDetial' attribute and assign different template to directive element in link function:

**Solution 2 app.js**

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("customerCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.customers = [{firstName:"Jimmy",lastName:"James",email:"jimmyj@gmail.com",phone:"000-00000-00"}];
})
.directive("customerView",function($compile){
return {
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{
        showDetail:"@",
        customerData:"="
    },
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        var showDetail = attrs.showDetail || false;
        var temp1 = '<div><img src=""/><div><span>{{customerData.firstName}} {{customerData.lastName}}</span></div><div><span>Tel:{{customerData.phone}}</span></div><div><span>mail:{{customerData.email}}</span></div></div>';
        var temp2 = '<div><img src=""/><div><span>{{customerData.firstName}} {{customerData.lastName}}</span></div></div>';
        var el = showDetail?$compile(temp1)(scope):$compile(temp2)(scope);
        element.append(el);
    }
};
});
```

**main.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="customerCtrl">
<h1>Simple</h1>
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
  <customer-view customer-data="customer"></customer-view>
</div>

<h1>More detail</h1>
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
    <customer-view customer-data="customer" show-detail="true"></customer-view>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller will maintain the customers model and pass the customer model to directive when you use ng-repaet to render all users.

Snapshot

[image]

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Ok, we need a controll attribute on the directive if we do not want to have multiple directives, in your case the `show-detail` But putting in the `ng-show` directive was the thing i want to avoid by creating a view factory because it will spread around in more advanced views

Comment: Answer updated. I used $compile to load different template according to the value you assigned to directive.